# Custom error with setCustomValidity avoid submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am facing a problem to customize the displayed error on a form. Here is the code who had problem :

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/done.html">
        <input type="text" id="query" name="query" 
               required 
               oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('What ?')">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I enter something into the input, the form is submitted without any problem. But if I just press submit, then it is impossible to submit it again even if the input is filled !

I must add `onkeypress="this.setCustomValidity('')"`.

Why `setCustomValidity` is not automatically cleaned after a while ? Is there another solution without a ton of js ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that your problem is that when you submit the form without data, it stops working and what worked was to execute the `setCustomValidity` function with an empty string.

Based on that a solution could be to add a `onsubmit="setCustomValidity('')"` on your form so it restarts every time you submit the form.

I can't tell you for sure because I don't know what that function `setCustomValidity` is doing. So try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Using `onsubmit` is the same as `onkeypress`. The `setCustomValidity` is a solution to specify error with a required attribute [as defined in HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-required-attribute)